# How is a String object instantiated?

Tags: c#, string

I need some clarification over the below code. I know that str.Length will return the number of characters in the string.

```
string str = "Sample string";
int length = str.Length;
```

My clarification is: Since we are not creating the string object, how the "Sample string" string is assigned to str variable?

Comment: You are creating a string object.

Comment: The compiler created the string object for you, then returned a reference.

Comment: Are you asking why you don't have to use the `new` keyword for strings?

Comment: and you can even do this: `int length = "Hello world".Length;` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string literal `"Sample string"` is created by the compiler, and will be stored in the assembly for you. When you assign it to your reference, you get a reference to that literal string.

There is a [`ldstr` instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr.aspx) that specifically loads literal strings from assembly metadata into a `string` object reference. It is that reference that has it's `Length` property checked.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is creating the string object for you.

Comment: Means it will create string object with passing the "assigned string" to the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

When you say `"Sample String"` in memory a new string object is created the same as if you called `new String("Sample String");`. This is just a macro to improve readability.

Comment: Not quite... there's no public constructor for String which takes a string, so the second is not syntactically valid.  But essentially, behind the scenes, it is being created for you.